# cant getJSON data from another domain

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

```
$.getJSON("http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=UtVVPkx83hGZ2wKUKX1_0w&_render=json&_callback=?",
    function(data) {
        $.each(data.value.items, function(Id,item) {
        $("<div/>").text(item.title).appendTo("#data");
    });
});
$.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/NewRequest/?Route=2406MOWLON&AD=1&CN=0&CS=E&Partner=testapic&_Serialize=JSON&jsoncallback=?",
    function(data) {
        $.each(data.value.items, function(Id,item) {
        $("<div/>").text(item.id).appendTo("#data2");
    });
});
```

the first json works fine, but the one from anywayanyday doesnt, what can be the problem?
thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `callback` instead of `jsoncallback` (what the callback's argument is depends on the service you're accessing). Also, it looks like the data looks something like this:

> {"Id":"9G8jJaYr39Qh18","Error":null}

And is not in a collection. The following code works for me:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/NewRequest/?Route=2406MOWLON&AD=1&CN=0&CS=E&Partner=testapic&_Serialize=JSON&callback=?", function(data) {
    $("#data2").text(data.Id);
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/WtxS3/

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `jsonp` as type and a callback in URL. However not all the services are actually supporting it. The response of the server must look like:

```
callback(JSON here)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it work but you are not processing the data correctly. Put `http://api.anywayanyday.com/api/NewRequest/?Route=2406MOWLON&AD=1&CN=0&CS=E&Partner=testapic&_Serialize=JSON&jsoncallback=?` in your browser and you get your response.

Also `$.each(data.Id)` needs to be used, not `$.each(data.value.items)`